# Spring Boot Specifications root's fetch function for join columns effects on performance

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

Suppose I have a Spring Boot Project that is structured as shown below, where I am storing Campus details, which has a lot of employees. Additionally many employees are also a part of one department only i.e. Department is a Master data Entity.

```
public class Campus {
    @Id
    private String campusNo;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee")
    private List<Employee>employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Employee {
    @Id
    private String employeeCode;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "campusNo", nullable = false)
    private Campus campus;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "departMentNo")
    private Department department;
}

public class Department {
    @Id
    private String departMentNo;
}
```

Now, if I want to use Specifications in my project to create configurable reports as shown below, which of the below two "fetch()" statements (marked as **Option 1** and **Option 2**) would be helpful for performance(reducing the number of "select" statements) and why? Both of them work. I'm only interested in knowing the merits and demerits (if any), of each statement.

```
public class CampusSpecification implements Specification<Campus> {
    private SearchCriteria searchCriteria;

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Campus> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        root.fetch("employeeList").fetch("department"); // Option 1
        root.fetch("employeeList"); // Option 2
        return criteriaBuilder.in(root.get("employeeList").get("department").get("departMentNo")).value(searchCriteria.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general note, I wouldn't worry about performance prematurely unless you notice that requests are taking quite long. I personally don't use the CriteriaBuilder when using Spring Boot/Hibernate as the statements become incredibly verbose compared to just using JPQL or SQL, but in the end what really matters for performance is the queries that are the result of this. Those might very well be the same for your 2 options.

If you want to check this, you could either monitor the queries on your database, or put this in your `application.properties`:

`spring.jpa.show-sql=true`

So you can see what kind of SQL is generated.

Mind you, a general tip of Hibernate themselves is to not use the entities when all you want to do is export them as a view.

For a fairly simple query like this with one ManyToOne join and one OneToMany join, I don't think overall performance is going to be that bad. Once you start joining multiple associations, that's when you probably should start splitting up queries in main table query and associated data table queries.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I do have multiple associations like these in my project. The above example is a breakdown of one such case. I have used your suggestion to show the kind of SQL that is being generated. I'm seeing that the number of "select" statements are essentially the same with or without using the "fetch" function. I just wanna be thorough though since my database is small right now and will keep on growing in the future. Which is why I wanted to explore the "fetch" function but the docs are not that clear though.

Comment: `fetch` would translate into a `JOIN FETCH` query in JPQL, which means it would be an SQL join but the resulting columns from the joined entity are already loaded into memory too. So that once you have your `campus` object and you call `getEmployeeList()`, it doesn't actually do another query right then, but just gets the data from memory.

Comment: So without knowing how the CriteriaBuilder really works internally, but seeing option 2 doesn't do the fetch for the second join, I would imagine option 1 does fewer queries in total (once you actually do something like `getEmployeeList().get(0).getDepartment()`

Comment: @Sebastian, So, in effect, the only demerit of using "fetch" would be the increased memory consumption on my application server, since the data has been "pre-fetched" and is stored in-memory. So, it's essentially a trade-off between the number of SQL queries fired to my database and the memory consumption in my application server. Which means if my database is huge, my application server should have enough memory to support the same.

Comment: @Joe correct, but if you're going to retrieve the associated data later anyway before the main data goes out of scope/can be garbage collected, you wouldn't save anything by delaying putting it in memory.

Comment: @Joe actually that's not the ONLY downside, but the other downside only comes into play of you have more ManyToOne associations like this. By preemptively joining them already, you multiply the amount of rows returned from the database at once. So if the campus has 100 employees and 100 classrooms, 1 campus with both those associations joined would already return 10.000 rows. In this scenario I'd start doing separate queries for the associated data, like I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Sebastian, so I'm better off not doing the "pre-fetching" then. Please correct me if I'm wrong but If I use only the `root.get()` statement, it means I'm avoiding fetching the corresponding Join entities? So, a separate SQL query would be fired if I do something like `getEmployeeList().get(0).getDepartment()`?

Comment: Yeah if you don't pre-fetch then getting the associated objects will do another query. In fact that query probably happens regardless UNLESS you configure it with `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`

Comment: @Sebastian, Okay. Thank You so much for your clarifications!